# mytop cant read mysql/conf.d Fatal error

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

## mytop

Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2)
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

As your question barely offers any valuable information, I can only give it an educated guess:

Are the permissions of the directory set the way that the user running mytop is able to read the file contents?

If you don't know, please provide the system account name of the user running mytop and the results of `ls -la /etc/mysql/conf.d`

Comment: The thing is that /etc/mysql/ does not exit. my mysql conf is in opt/lampstack-5.6.26-0/mysql/my.cnf
How do i change the confg path for mysql

Comment: You would need to look for that information in your mytop configuration and change the path in there. Another option would be to set a symbolic link, for example like `ln -s opt/lampstack-5.6.26-0/mysql/ /etc/mysql`.